# Are dialogs supported in jquery-ui Version 1.11.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking at legacy javascript code and am attempting to add a popup dialog to a webpage.

I added the dialog html/script to the page. At runtime, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

The client is using the following:

> jquery-ui version 1.11.0 (circa 2014).
>
> jquery version 2.1.4

Were dialogs not supported back in jquery-ui 1.11.0?

Before I upgrade everything here to the latest versions of jquery/jquery-ui, 
I want to be sure that this a version issue before I initiate of upgrading.

Comment: Check recent edits pls; typo on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  As can be found by going to the jquery ui website and navigating to the older documentation (found on the bottom left), you can find the api documentation for 1.11 containing the Dialog widget.

https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/category/widgets/ 
https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/dialog/

Comment: Thx, That helped verify it was supported. Turns out that client was using a customized download of the jquery-ui.js library which did not include dialog support.